# Issue with Creating Model Relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model

I have 3 main models in my program; User, Country, City.

- User and Country have a many-to-many relationship, which I join with
  a Trip model.
- User and City have a many-to-many relationship, which I join with a
  Visit model.
- Country and City have a one-to-many relationship.

When I run `rails db:migrate` I get no errors and all appears well, however when I try and seed data or go into the console to create a City it will not save. Any Users or Countries will be successfully created and I am able to build relationships between them.

See my models below.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

    before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
    #attr_accessible :user_name, :email
    validates_confirmation_of :password
    has_secure_password

    validates :user_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 25 }
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
    validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
    validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    has_many :trips
    has_many :visits
    has_many :countries, through: :trips
    has_many :cities, through: :visits


end
```

**city.rb**

```
class City < ApplicationRecord

    has_many :visits
    has_many :users, through: :visits
    belongs_to :country

end
```

**country.rb**

```
class Country < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :trips
  has_many :cities
  has_many :users, through: :trips

end
```

**trip.rb**

```
class Trip < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :country
    belongs_to :user

end
```

**visit.rb**

```
class Visit < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :city
    belongs_to :user

end
```

Originally I did not even have the Visit model, I just joined both many-to-many relationships through the Trip model. However, in trying to solve the issue I separated it.

Any help with this issue would be appreciated. If you need more information just let me know.

Comment: Are you sure you have migrations for all of your models? db:migrate will return successfully if it had nothing to do. What sort of message are you getting when you're trying to save? (Try using save! instead of save from the console if it's just returning false.)

Comment: I get `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Country must exist` when a do save!. I have countries and I tried something like `Country.find(1).cities << [City.create(name: "Toronto")]` in the hope that assigning the city to the country as I create it would help but no luck.

Comment: Are you saving the city with a country_id?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by modeling it properly:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
  has_many :users, through: :visits
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :trips
  has_many :cities
  has_many :users, through: :trips 
end

class Trip < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :visits
  has_many :cities, through: :visits
end

class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :city
  has_one :country, through: :city
  has_one :user, through: :trip
end

# added
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  has_many :trips
  has_many :visits, through: :trips
  has_many :countries, through: :trips
  has_many :cities, through: :visits
end
```

This creates a one to many association between Trip and Visit and avoids duplicating the `user_id` foreign key on both.

In Rails 5 one of the major changes is that `belongs_to` associations are non-optional by default.

So if you attempt to create a city without a country the validations will fail. But if you create the city from an existing record:

```
Country.first.cities.create!(name: 'Toronto')
```

Or pass a record:

```
City.create!(name: 'Toronto', country: Country.first)
```

The validation will pass.

You can also set the association as optional which is the behaviour in Rails 4:

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
  has_many :users, through: :visits
  belongs_to :country, optional: true
end
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested however, it still does not work when I try either attempt to create a City. I get the error -  `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'country_id' for City`. Is my User model set up correctly as well?

Comment: `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError` means that you have not created the column `country_id`. If you have created such a migration you may have forgotten to run it.

Comment: Otherwise you can generate the migration by running `rails g migration add_country_id_to_cities country_id:belongs_to`

Comment: Also make sure that visit has a `trip_id` foreign key column, and remove the  `user_id` column if present.

Comment: Okay, I think we are close! I am now able to create and save Cities. I also am able to assign users to countries and am able to assign cities to a country. Although, I now am getting an issue when trying to assign a Cities to a User and vice versa. Example: `User.first.cities << [City.first]` gives me the following error; `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly: Cannot modify association 'User#cities' because it goes through more than one other association.`

Answer (score 0):

as city has_many users through visits, then you have to declare has_many :visits inside city model below is sample code probably can help you problem

```
class City < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :visits
    has_many :users, through: :visits
    belongs_to :country
end
```

when you create city in your console, make sure you gave country_id as in belongs_to country, here is a sample code:

```
@city = City.new
@city.country = Country.first
# @city.name = .... # your seed code 
@city.save
```

Comment: Thanks, I have added that in as well as to the to the User model but I am still having the same issue. 

I have edited my code above to add the changes.